# How to have a glyphicon appear on hover in a <td>?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, hover

I have a table with data that I want the user to be able to delete per row. But to not clutter my UI with trashcans, I want the trashcan to appear only when hovering over the record. I am using Bootstrap and jQuery, but I am having a hard time getting this right.

What I have until now (`$("#properties")` is my `tbody`):

```
function add_property(prop) {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);

    $("#properties").append("<tr>"+
        '<td id="td'+r+'" class="property"><div class="col-sm-11">' + prop + 
        '</div><div  class="col-sm-1"><span id="div'+r+'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="display:none"></div></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" name="'+prop+'"></td>'+
    "</tr>");

    $("#td"+r).hover(function() {
        $("#div"+r).css("display", "inline");
    }, function() {
        $("#div"+r).css("display", "none");
    });
}
```

I use the random number, because the records are created dynamically.

Currently, everything is jumping around when I am hovering over the `<td>`s.

**Update** of course I want to be able to click the trashcan to delete the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css without any javascript for that:

```
<div class="col-sm-1"><span id="div'+r+'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#properties div .glyphicon.glyphicon-trash {
    display: none;
}
#properties td:hover div .glyphicon.glyphicon-trash {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, putting the `td:hover` in between never occured to me ;-). Using `visibility` instead of `display` really fixed it.

Comment: Glad I could help. I used the `inline` because this is what you used in your javascript. The diff between visibility and display is really depends on your needs/ui.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to both name and icon class to make them same line

.inline {
   display:inline-block;
}

and make the visibilty , hidden/visible on hover the div id

bellow a working snippet

```js
function add_property(prop) {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);

    $("#properties").append("<tr>"+
        '<td id="td'+r+'" class="property"><div class="col-sm-11 inline">' + prop + 
        '</div><div  class="col-sm-1 inline"><span id="div'+r+'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="visibility:hidden"></div></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" name="'+prop+'"></td>'+
    "</tr>");

    $("#td"+r).hover(function() {
        $("#div"+r).css("visibility", "visible");
    }, function() {
        $("#div"+r).css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
}

$("#btn").on("click",function(e){
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
  add_property("name"+r); 
});
```

```css
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}

.glyphicon-trash:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<button id="btn">add</button>
<table id="properties">

</table>
```